# JEditorPane - IMG tag without HEIGHT parameter

Tags: java, html, swing

In JEditorPane with html content:

```
...
<img src="x.jpg" width="100" border="0" />
...
```

(e.g image is (500x700))

Firefox or chrome or any other browsers view this image as 100x140 on page

```
(140 = 700 / (500/100))
```

but
JEditorPane show it as 100x20(i think 20 is default).
is this a bug?

What can i do, i cant change html sources because its on CD-ROM.

thanks in advance

Furkan

Edit: Referenced html file content:

```
<html msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" user="http://www.etiam.com/namespace" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 12 April 2005), see www.w3.org">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
<title></title>

</head>
<body vlink="#ffff00" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0)" alink="#ffff00" link="#ffff00">
<h1>
  <u>PAT 143</u>
</h1>
<h2>
  ID : 100043
</h2>
<h2>
  Birthdate : 2001/01/01
</h2>
<br>


<ul>
  <li>
    Study date: 2005/01/01 00:00<br><br>
  </li>
  <li style="list-style-position: outside; list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none">
    <table border="0" width="90%" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
          <a href="aa1.htm"><img src="0.jpg" border="0" width="128">
          </a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <a href="aa2.htm"><img src="3.jpg" border="0" width="128">
          </a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <a href="aa3.htm"><img src="5.jpg" border="0" width="128">
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p align="center">
      click an image to select a series
    </p>
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<p align="center">
  <a href="/index.htm"><img src="retacc.gif" border="0">
</a>    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is 20 the line height in your case?

Comment: i edited message with html file.

Comment: could you post sscce (http://sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Firefox or chrome or any other browsers view this image as 100x140 on page

How FF & Chrome deal with invalid HTML is their business.

> but JEditorPane show it as 100x20(i think 20 is default). is this a bug?

No, unless you are referring to a 'bug' in the HTML.  GI/GO.

Comment: What is your point?  At one stage, almost 50% of the code of IE was **for dealing with malformed HTML.**  It is not that surprising that browser manufacturers have the browser do a 'proportional scale' of the original image based on the single size attribute provided.  But JEditorPane is an altogether 'differently abled' HTML renderer - very small & light with almost no ability to correct errors in the source document.  JEP was never intended as a full browsing component.